# Reload Text In Submit Button When "Back" Button Is Pressed

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a HTML form where the user selects a file to upload then presses the "Submit" button.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<br>
<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" onclick="changeButtonText()" id="submit">
</form>
```

When the "Submit" button is clicked, the text in the button changes from "Submit" to "Please wait..." and the user is sent to "upload.php" when the upload is complete.

```
<script>
function changeButtonText() {
    document.getElementById("submit").value="Please wait..."; 
}
</script>
```

If the user presses the "Back" button in their browser, they go back to the form page, but the text in the button still says "Please wait...". I've fixed this with the following code in the form page.

```
<body onunload="">
```

I'm just wondering if this is the best way to revert the text in the "Submit" button from "Please wait..." back to "Submit" if the "Back" button is pressed? There is nothing else on the page that the user could lose by doing this, I just thought I'd ask if this was the best way to do it.

Comment: Why not initialize the text of you submit button with `Submit` value, each time the JavaScript is loaded ?

Comment: @Zeratops, the submit button value is already set to "Upload File", but this is not reloaded if the user presses the "Back" button in their browser.